# How to read values of Theano's LogisticRegression class predictions within DeepLearningTutorials package?

Tags: python, classification, theano, deep-learning

I am using [Theano's LogisticRegression sample code](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html) and i have not modified the code in the given package at all and i'm using the same data.

I need to read the values of prediction which are within (self.y_pred) field in LogisticRegression class and also the values of prediction probabilities which are in self.p_y_given_x field of the same class.

They are tensortype and tensorvariables and i don't know how to read/print them. I need them to do a postprocessing but i can't get access to the values. The values should be read after training which should be here around the star charachters.

```
while (epoch < n_epochs) and (not done_looping):
    epoch = epoch + 1
    for minibatch_index in xrange(n_train_batches):

        minibatch_avg_cost = train_model(minibatch_index)
        # iteration number
        iter = (epoch - 1) * n_train_batches + minibatch_index

        if (iter + 1) % validation_frequency == 0:
            # compute zero-one loss on validation set
            validation_losses = [validate_model(i)
                                 for i in xrange(n_valid_batches)]
            this_validation_loss = numpy.mean(validation_losses)

            print('epoch %i, minibatch %i/%i, validation error %f %%' % \
                (epoch, minibatch_index + 1, n_train_batches,
                this_validation_loss * 100.))

            # if we got the best validation score until now
            if this_validation_loss < best_validation_loss:
                #improve patience if loss improvement is good enough
                if this_validation_loss < best_validation_loss *  \
                   improvement_threshold:
                    patience = max(patience, iter * patience_increase)

                best_validation_loss = this_validation_loss
                # test it on the test set

                test_losses = [test_model(i)
                               for i in xrange(n_test_batches)]
                test_score = numpy.mean(test_losses)

                print(('     epoch %i, minibatch %i/%i, test error of best'
                   ' model %f %%') %
                    (epoch, minibatch_index + 1, n_train_batches,
                     test_score * 100.))

        if patience <= iter:
            done_looping = True
            break

end_time = time.clock()
print(('Optimization complete with best validation score of %f %%,'
       'with test performance %f %%') %
             (best_validation_loss * 100., test_score * 100.))
print 'The code run for %d epochs, with %f epochs/sec' % (
    epoch, 1. * epoch / (end_time - start_time))
print >> sys.stderr, ('The code for file ' +
                      os.path.split(__file__)[1] +
                      ' ran for %.1fs' % ((end_time - start_time)))
#read the values here and print them
#**********************************
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sgd_optimization_mnist()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile a function that gives back the prediction.

This code may not work exactly, but this is the idea:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

# Create some data with 100 samples, 10 features 
X = np.random.randn(100, 10)
X_sym = T.fmatrix('X')
# Create prediction function
predict_function = theano.function(inputs=[X_sym], outputs=self.y_pred)

# See the actual prediction
print(predict_function(X))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the code that worked for me as answered by Kyle. It returns the values of the prediction classes and i print a report out of it.

```
classifier = LogisticRegression(input=x, n_in=train_set_x.get_value(borrow=True).shape[1], n_out=25)

# the cost we minimize during training is the negative log likelihood of
# the model in symbolic format
cost = classifier.negative_log_likelihood(y)

# compiling a Theano function that computes the mistakes that are made by
# the model on a minibatch
test_model = theano.function(inputs=[index],
        outputs=classifier.errors(y),
        givens={
            x: test_set_x[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size],
            y: test_set_y[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size]})

validate_model = theano.function(inputs=[index],
        outputs=classifier.errors(y),
        givens={
            x: valid_set_x[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size],
            y: valid_set_y[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size]})

predict = theano.function(inputs=[],
        outputs=classifier.y_pred,
        givens={
            x: test_set_x})
# compute the gradient of cost with respect to theta = (W,b)
g_W = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=classifier.W)
g_b = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=classifier.b)

# specify how to update the parameters of the model as a list of
# (variable, update expression) pairs.
updates = [(classifier.W, classifier.W - learning_rate * g_W),
           (classifier.b, classifier.b - learning_rate * g_b)]

# compiling a Theano function `train_model` that returns the cost, but in
# the same time updates the parameter of the model based on the rules
# defined in `updates`
train_model = theano.function(inputs=[index],
        outputs=cost,
        updates=updates,
        givens={
            x: train_set_x[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size],
            y: train_set_y[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size]})

###############
# TRAIN MODEL #
###############
print '... training the model'
# early-stopping parameters
patience = 50000  # look as this many examples regardless
patience_increase = 2  # wait this much longer when a new best is
                              # found
improvement_threshold = 0.995  # a relative improvement of this much is
                              # considered significant
validation_frequency = min(n_train_batches, patience / 2)
                              # go through this many
                              # minibatche before checking the network
                              # on the validation set; in this case we
                              # check every epoch

best_params = None
best_validation_loss = numpy.inf
test_score = 0.
start_time = time.clock()

done_looping = False
epoch = 0
while (epoch < n_epochs) and (not done_looping):
    epoch = epoch + 1
    #********************here i call the function and report based on returned class predictions.
    report(predict())
```